# Can't zoom in or move around

Tags: sculpting

Everything was fine a week ago but when I openend my project turns out I can't zoom in closely. Like, I can zoom but not into the body or close to it, I also can't move around with shift mousewheel anymore, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the situation, which is sadly not possible to see here (it could help if you attach a picture of your view), i would recommend to press <kbd>Numpad Decimal</kbd> or go in the "View" Menu and click on "Frame Selected".

If you zoom in enough on a small detail, the amount of movement with the mouse seems to get drastically reduced.

Once you use "Frame Selected" <kbd>Numpad Decimal</kbd> or even "Frame all" with <kbd>Home</kbd>, you should have a normal responsiveness of your mouse navigation in the 3D Viewport.

**Update:**
The camera (not camera object!) is essentially stationary when you zoom and has a limit as to how far it can zoom in. To avoid this, it's recommended to either reposition the camera with functions like mentioned above or by just using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd>** to move the camera along it's **Z-axis**. That way you can move closer and readjust the zoom needed. I'd zoom out before moving closer though.

Comment: True! Once I did the frame all option, the mouse wheel started working again. Just wondering, what made it stop zooming in.

Answer (score 0):

Try locking the view to the 3D cursor. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the sidebar below, press the *View* tab, and open the *View Lock* menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible work around I found ; though kind of silly... Adding and deleting a camera, or enter Camera View and then out.

Update: The other answerer is correct selecting "Lock to 3D Cursor" in the View Tab! I am unable to upvote at the moment but thank you!

For my random work around: I first added a camera (since I had deleted the default one), switched to camera view, and then moved the viewport gizmo.

[image: Add Camera:]

[image: Enter Camera View]

By this next 3rd image, I am able to zoom in closely
[image: Exit out of Camera View by moving perspective gizmo]

Then of course you could just import into a new project last resort haha.